# I have an rasterized text image. Can i convert it into text file?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I rasterized my complete text file and then adjusted accordingly. Now I want to restore these images into text files. Is it possible any way?

Comment: You can try to use websites like https://www.myfreeocr.com/en to convert images to text. There are many of similar sites.

Answer (score 2):

OCR (=optical character recognition) software has been widely available over 25 years. Some scanners have it as a bonus and it's included to Adobe Acrobat.

Search for OCR software, you get plenty of hits. One example:

[OCR software reviews November 2016](http://www.toptenreviews.com/business/software/best-ocr-software/)

The results are very much dependent on the quality of your image, careful redaction is a must and non-english character sets may not be supported by all packages..

Have a backup of your file? Use it, if possible. Even a little old version that needs some retyping is better than OCR. Both need the same care (=100% check).

Answer (score 1):

Unless your document is still open and you can still Undo the rasterization, there's no way to convert a rasterized image back into a text layer, if that's what you meant by *text files*.

You probably want to try softwares with OCR tools (or online tools like [this](http://www.onlineocr.net/) one) to see if you can get the text recognized. Not 100% accurate but probably your best bet.